# Set window's upper left corner icon in wxMSW

Tags: windows, icons, mingw, wxwidgets

I'm working on a project with wxWidgets (the 2.9 branch). I'm using gcc and makefiles - most of the questions I've found on this deal with Visual Studio.

The problem is, I've created an icon with IcoFX, and it includes several different sizes of icon, including the 16x16 icons that should show up in the corner of the window. The icon does show up in the Windows 7 task bar, but not in the corner of the window or in the Alt+Tab menu.

My resource file looks like this:

```
#include "wx/msw/wx.rc"
1 ICON "images/icon-win.ico"
```

No matter what I put as the icon's identifier (tried 1, 0, strings, wx***) it doesn't change anything.

I am using windres to compile the resource file to COFF format, which is then linked in with the final executable.

I've also tried wxFrame::SetIcon, which hasn't worked either.

Is there a trick to setting the window's icon? I've seen a couple ways to do it that involve the Windows API, but I'd rather not go there if I don't have to. I thought it was supposed to show up automatically when you put it in the resources file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your resource file:

```
frame_icon ICON "images/icon-win.ico"
```

Add this line to your frame constructor

```
SetIcon(wxICON(frame_icon));
```

Comment: Huh, well I don't know why using a number as the identifier wouldn't do anything, but this worked. Thanks!

Comment: C++ identifiers must begin with a letter. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Comment: It compiled fine when I used a number, it just didn't do anything. As it turns out, it's not actually using an identifier. I found this in the wx headers:
`#define wxICON(X) wxIcon(wxT(#X))`
So I suppose it was looking for a resource called "1" when its ID was the number 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`frame->SetIcon(wxIcon(wxT("icon.ico"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO));`

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Comment: @AaronHall -> You can set icon at the upper left corner of the window on your wxFrame without using any resource file.

<code>frame_object_name->SetIcon(wxIcon(wxT("contents/myicon.ico"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO));</code>

This is an alternative solution of this question. Just if anyone doesn't want to use resource file, then this is the one line of solution

Comment: I was reviewing answers, and one-liners sometimes get flagged, I didn't flag it, but I figure you should probably edit your answer to contain your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found putting the icon in the resource file means it shows up on the task bar and as the executable icon. To set it as the frame icon you need to do the following:

```
frame->SetIcon(wxICON(1));
```